# uninstall module that depends on relation module, which is disabled

Tags: 7

I am a maintainer of the [crm_core](https://www.drupal.org/project/crm_core) module. The Drupal7 version depends on the [relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) module to provide relationships between contacts. The depend module can not be uninstalled while the relation module is disabled.

Is there a solution? Or, is this one of the limitations of disabling modules, which might be why disable was dropped in Drupal8.

[2273255 -
Can't uninstall crm_core_relationship when relation module has been disabled](https://www.drupal.org/project/crm_core/issues/2273255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue described in [Can't uninstall crm_core_relationship when relation module has been disabled](https://www.drupal.org/project/crm_core/issues/2273255) is that `crm_core_relationship_uninstall()` is calling functions defined in a disabled module. When a module is disabled, Drupal won't load it, and all the module functions won't be available.

Either `crm_core_relationship_uninstall()` first loads that module file with  [`drupal_load('module', 'relation')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_load/7.x), before calling its functions, or the code in `relation_delete()` and `relation_type_delete()` is duplicated in functions accessible from `crm_core_relationship_uninstall()`.

That issue isn't present in Drupal 8, as in Drupal 8 modules can only installed or not installed; they cannot be anymore disabled as in Drupal 7.

Comment: I used the drupal_load function, and it works! [changes](https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/crm_core-2273255/-/compare/7.x-1.x...2273255-unintall-disabled-relation?w=1)